# Error formatting a string when naming in Powershell using -ChildPath

Tags: powershell

I'm converting CSV files with thousands of rows to independent plain text files. Each file has a name `fileName-Part{0:D2}.txt`. Is there a way to start naming from 1 and not from 0? This generates an error: `fileName-Part{1:D2}.txt`

> Error formatting a string: Index (zero based) must be greater than or
> equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list..

What I'm using:

```
$outputfolder = 'C:\generacionaudios\500\textfiles'
Import-Csv C:\generacionaudios\500\500.csv -Encoding utf8 | ForEach-Object { $i = 0 } {
    $path = Join-Path $outputfolder -ChildPath ('fileName-Part{0:D2}.txt' -f $i++)
    $_ | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content $path -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Comment: change `$i = 0` to `$i = 1`

Comment: Alternatively, change `$++` to `++$i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it by changing

```
ForEach-Object { $i = 0 }
```

to

```
ForEach-Object { $i = 1 }
```